# What is an example of a second order differential equation for which it is known that there are no smooth solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would really appreciate if someone could just write down for me one example of a second order, or higher, differential equation for which it is known that there are no smooth solutions; and it's fine if it's a partial differential equation.

At first I thought it would be easy to either come up with an example or else find one by searching google/wiki/arxiv; but now I am not so sure.

I have a thing for non-smooth functions, and it just bothers me that I don't even know a single example of this type of differential equation.  Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you just take any old $C^1$ function that's not smooth and produce a differential equation from that? For example $y' = |x|$? Or if you want an even uglier answer, start with a continuous nowhere-differentiable function, $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$. By the fundamental theorem of calculus, the function $F: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\;\mathrm{d}t$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ with $F'(x) = f(x)$, or in other words: $F$ is a solution to the differential equation $y' = f$ on $(a,b)$. Or did you want your DE to satisfy some additional "niceness" property?

Comment: First of all, I got a bit stuck trying to integrate the Weierstrass function and then finding a second order differential equation; but I was even more confused about how I was going to go about showing the differential equation I got didn't have other solutions that were smooth.

Comment: See the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_existence_theorem).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are already *first order* linear partial differential equations with smooth coefficients which do not admit any smooth solutions.

Hans Lewy produced the first [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewy%27s_example#CITEREFMizohata1962) of such a PDE. The equation reads 
$$\left[-i\partial_x+\partial_y-2(x+iy)\partial_z\right]u(x,y,z)=f(x,y,z),\qquad(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^{3}.$$
The equation does not have distribution solutions in any neighbourhood of any point in $\mathbb R^3$ provided $f=f(x,y,z)$ is not a real analytic function (it can be smooth though).

The original paper by Lewy is nice, clear and less than 4 pages long (freely available [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~yhhuang/266.09w/lewy.pdf)).

Comment: An interesting detail about Lewy's paper is that it doesn't cite any other works.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the partial differential equations associated to the [isometric embedding problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_embedding_theorem) of the hyperbolic plane into Euclidean 3-space. In $C^1$ there exists a solution by Nash-Kuiper theorem, but it is known classically that there cannot be solutions that are twice or more continuously differentiable.

Comment: Is the form of these partial differential equation known, or is it only known that they exist abstractly?

Comment: They are known. See, e.g. www.deaneyang.com/papers/gunther.pdf

Answer (score 4):

How about you take the differential equation

$ \frac{dy}{dx} = |x|  $

This is a linear non-homogeneous differential equation, whose solution is $C^1$ but not smooth at $x=0$.

Comment: The solution is $y = \frac12 sgn(x) x^2 + c$.

Comment: The solution is not $y=\frac{1}{2}|x|^2$, since we have $\frac{d\frac{1}{2}∣x∣}{dx}=sgn(x)|x|=x$. So I'm wondering if you know the solution about x = 0, and also how can I derive this solution?

Comment: @Matt: The solution is a piecewise quadratic function. It is $-x^2/2 + C$ for $x \leq 0$ and $+x^2/2 + C$ for $x \geq 0$. I got this by integrating $|t|$ from $0$ to $x$.